# Unable to run an ipad application

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, ios-simulator

I need some help. I have an ipad application downloaded from App-Store (free) and now i want to run the app on any simulator. I tried many simulator but i got failed. Even when i am try to run it in MAC OS system, then it is saying that unable to run.

So i need guidance to run the following app on a simulator.

the name of application is :   "apsley tailors"

download from : https://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/apsley-tailors/id473679792?mt=8

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

You simply can't run App Store-applications on the Simulator.
The iOS Simulator is intended for developers: you can only run apps of which you have the source on the simulator. The App Store binary is compiled for ARM while the simulator expects an Intel-build. The only way to get it run is compiling it for Intel which is impossible without the source code.

Comment: Ok. If i have .app file which is source code... than how can i run it on a simulator. And which is the best simulator for it.

Comment: There is only one simulator - so asking which is the best makes your question even more confusing.

Comment: An .app file isn't the source code, it's a compiled binary..
And it's compiled for an ARM iOS-device so you can't run it on the Simulator. As stated above, there's indeed only one simulator.

Answer (score 0):

You can't run it on simulator.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the source code, your open it in Xcode, compile it, and then run it on the simulator or a device registered to your developer account.

But, source code doesn't have a `.app` extension - so I doubt that is what you have.