# not able run .app in mac lion os but no source code

Tags: iphone, ios

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Unable to run an ipad application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13535283/unable-to-run-an-ipad-application)

I have an .app file built for ipad. Can i run it in mac lion os? I tried to run it on mac but i got a message box with following error.

**"You can't open the application appname.app because it is not supported on this type of mac"**

Please guide me how to run an .app file in mac lion os, xcode and in a simulator on mac os.

Thanks!

Comment: If you get the source code and project for the iPad app, you can build it to run under your simulator.  Good luck!

Comment: How many times do we have to tell you "no, it's impossible" before you will understand? You already asked twice: [1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13535849/how-to-run-app-file-ipad), [2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13535283/unable-to-run-an-ipad-application).

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't run it.  iOS and OSX apps are completely different types of apps, and an app designated for one can't be run on the other.  They are different architectures, and would require a rewrite of an application to run it on the other.

Answer (score 0):

Man, that is an iPad app. You need to run it in an iPad.